# Cadastrar um usuário "admin" ao executar a aplicação c# mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, visual-studio, owin

boa tarde, preciso de alguma ideia para que um sistema web crie automaticamente um user Admin assim que eu execute(abra) a aplicação.

ou seja, ao executar a aplicação com um banco zerado, para que eu não precise registrar nenhum usuário antes de logar, o sistema já gera esse usuário automaticamente ao ser executado.

estou usando asp net MVC, no visual Studio 2017.

Comment: Infelizmente eu não posso comentar. Nota: Que em uma base dados as informações não irão ficar salvas na memória e desaparecer assim que fechar a aplicação. Bem.. Criar um utilizador automaticamente assim que vc abrir a aplicação é algo simples, mas o que vc quer que aconteça quando vc fechar a aplicação? Que o utilizador seja descartado? Que o utilizador continue, para uma próxima acção de abrir a aplicação?

Answer (score 1):

Boa tarde Paulo. Da uma olhada no Seed do Entity FrameWork

https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/5d065a/seed-database-in-entityframework/

Comment: Esse link pode ser uma boa sugestão, mas sua resposta não terá validade se um dia o link deixar de funcionar. Além disso, é importante para a comunidade ter conteúdo aqui no site mesmo. Seria melhor incluir mais detalhes na sua resposta. Um resumo do conteúdo do link já ajudaria bastante! Saiba mais sobre o assunto neste item do nosso FAQ da Comunidade: [Queremos respostas que contenham somente links?](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/42/74)

Answer (score 1):

Caso esteja trabalhando com [Code First](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/migrations-and-deployment-with-the-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application) poderá usar o Seed do Entity.
Para habilitá-lo execute no [NuGet](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/tools/package-manager-console): `Enable-Migrations`

```
 protected override void Seed(ContosoUniversity.DAL.SchoolContext context)
    {
        //  This method will be called after migrating to the latest version.

        //  You can use the DbSet<T>.AddOrUpdate() helper extension method 
        //  to avoid creating duplicate seed data. E.g.
        //
        //    context.People.AddOrUpdate(
        //      p => p.FullName,
        //      new Person { FullName = "Andrew Peters" },
        //      new Person { FullName = "Brice Lambson" },
        //      new Person { FullName = "Rowan Miller" }
        //    );
        //
    }
```

Fonte: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/migrations-and-deployment-with-the-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application